# How do I list all files in a directory for a directory name stored in a tensor?

Tags: file, tensorflow

I have a placeholder which will be fed by a string value. The string value represents a path to some directory name. In that directory there are different ".jpg" files. How can I ask TensorFlow to list all of those files?
In other words, I want to add a node to my computation graph which will result in listing the directory, if I run it through my session. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You don't need TF to do that. TF is not a "file system" library.

Comment: How would you do that? Let's say that you have videos in each of these folders and you have a very complicated sampling process which will give you the file address of those video files. I want to use tf.data.Dataset and right now my iterator.next gives me the file address of the sampled video and the label of its class. My next step is to apply a parse function to dataset which will convert all of these file_addresses to actual frames of the video.

Comment: What does this have to do with listing files inside a directory?

Comment: If I will be able to list those files, then I will be able to select some of them and use them as my data for my next batch during my training.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either using or not TensorFlow. I will only show you how you can list all files in a certain directory using TensorFlow, using [`tf.gfile.ListDirectory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/ListDirectory). You don't even need placeholders (in this case).

```
import tensorflow as tf


dir_path = "."
print(tf.gfile.ListDirectory(dir_path))
```

Comment: The way I solved my problem was to convert those directories to tf records and then used them to process data. Your method is correct, however, it just works with strings defined in python. What I wanted was to convert a directory name which is stored in a tensor into some images from that directory.

Comment: @Siavash What do you mean by "convert a directory name which is stored in a tensor into some images from that directory"? You want to read images from a directory and store them in some data structure in TF? If that's the case, it wasn't clear (to me) from your original post/question.